# Increase Android development speed

Tags: android, performance

being a Java/Linux advocate, and having programmed my first Android app a while ago, nowadays I'm building a similar one this time in WPF (it's likely to be run in WP7). I have to admit that so far Eclipse/ADT seems to be no match to VisualStudio 9 in regards to development speed. The latter excels in the build/run speed cycle (it's obvious being Eclipse a java based app). Being my development HW an i3 laptop/4GB RAM/Win7 x64, my questions are:

- Could I get a similar development speed I have today in VS9 in the "Android" environmnent if I had a state of the art processor (i7 ?)
- Would I have a performance boost if I worked in a Linux partition in my laptop?

Any additional hints are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: A better processor and a solid-state hard drive would definitely help out.

Comment: Good point, I had forgotten the SSD factor.

Comment: You don't have to use eclipse for android development - you can set up your project to build from an ant script and edit it with anything you like.  Also one bottleneck can be the deployment speed to a device - a fast android device may be a noticeable improvement, but the real win is if you can also build your project to run on your development machine (itself, not the emulator) and do most of your iterative testing there.

Comment: The build process itself is device-agnostic. It's really only the uploading and installing when launching that varies from device to device, in my experience. I've noticed that installing to internal memory is *always* faster than installing to the SD card. I wouldn't recommend running the Ant script for regular debugging, as it may be much slower due to key signing and various optimizations. For release builds, however, absolutely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary reason ADT feels bulky and slow is because it is constantly rebuilding in the background. This proves useful when showing compile errors and warnings as you type, but when working on larger projects—especially when making changes to the manifest, XML files (including layouts, drawables and strings) and resources—the IDE will regularly lock up with a build progress bar, as some changes require a rebuild to complete.

You can disable automatic building via the Project menu. I use this regularly when making changes to layouts, but enable it again when writing code.

As for hardware: it appears that `aapt` runs only on one core, and from my experience, it runs noticeably faster on faster cores vs. more cores. (This is anecdotal, since the comparison here is a PC with two 2.11 GHz cores vs. a laptop with two 1.8 GHz cores.)

A colleague uses Linux for development; I'll inquire if he has noticed any speed increase since switching from Windows.

Comment: Thanks Paul, actually I have a huge xml layout file (it contains a ViewFlipper with several layouts) and it certainly takes a long time in  the rebuilding process when it's modified. I'll give it a shot.